# "Internal server error" when migrating Parse to Heroku/AWS

Tags: swift, mongodb, heroku, parse-platform

I am evacuating the sinking Parse ship.

- Migrated data to MongoDB
- Tested connection with MongoDB while using api.parse.com
- Hosted Parse server on Heroku \ AWS both
- Tested the servers by going to their URL and seeing 'I dream of being web site"
- Updated the appid, master key, and mongo uri for AWS and Heroku servers

In my app delegate when I use,

```
let config = ParseClientConfiguration(block:{ (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in
    ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "APPID"
    ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "myClientKey"
  ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "my AWS or Heroku server"
  })
Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(config)
```

And I try to connect to update the MongoDB database, I get the following error,

```
[Error]: {"code":1,"message":"Internal server error."} (Code: 1, Version: 1.12.0)
Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."
```

Any help appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue, it was a silly mistake, the problem was that I had an @symbol in the password and I had not url-encoded it. When I escaped the symbol and restarted the server it started working.

Comment: Hi mate, I have been facing the same issue. Which password are you talking about?

Comment: Hi, the password that you set for the database inside the Mongolab website. Remove the @ from the same